# Understanding Sylow-Groups

Tags: abstract-algebra, sylow-theory

I just read that a Group of order $12$ consists of Sylow-Groups of order $3$ and $2$.

I also read that the number of elements of $Syl_2G$ is greater or equal than $4$. Why is that?

Also, how can I choose $G$ so that I have exactly $1$ $Syl_2G$ and $4$ $Syl_3G$? At least I think I need $4$ $Syl_3G$. But to be sure I want to understand how to know how many elements in such a Sylow-Group are.

Comment: I am pretty sure you are missing information (or are failing to provide it). **If** $G$ is or order $12$, **and** it is not abelian, then it cannot have both a single Sylow $3$-subgroup and a single Sylow $2$-subgroup (because then they would be normal, $G$ would be isomorphic to their direct product, and hence would be abelian). By Sylow's Theorems, the number of $3$-Sylow subgroup must both divide $12$ and be congruent to $1$ modulo $3$; so it has either one or 4. The number of $2$-Sylow subgroups must divide $12$ and be congruent to $1$ mod $2$, so either 1 or 3.

Comment: In addition, a Sylow $2$-subgroup of a group of order $12$ **must** have order $4$, because the order of a Sylow $p$-subgroup of a finite group $G$ is the largest power of $p$ that divides the order of $G$. So, at this point, I think what you really need to do is learn the Sylow Theorems, which will no doubt answer all your questions. Right now, you seem to be ignoring them for some reason.

Comment: Finally, you tagged this “abelian groups”. An abelian group of order divisible by $p$ has *exactly* one Sylow $p$-subgroup. Are you sure you mean abelian groups here?

Comment: @ArturoMagidin $G$ isn't abelian. And you're right, by Sylow theorem we have either $1$ or $4$ $3$-Sylow and $1$ or $3$-Sylow. I understand now that the order of the Sylow-groups follow from the theorem, thanks. Ill try coming up with an example for my other question above

Comment: If $G$ is not assumed abelian, then *please* remove the [abelian-groups] tag: it is misleading!

Comment: As to finding a group of order $12$ with exactly one Sylow $2$-subgroup and exactly four Sylow $3$-subgroups... there aren’t that many groups of order $12$. Try $A_4$.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin Let's assume $G$ is cyclic group $C_{12}$ with operation multiplication so that $a^k=\underbrace{a\cdot...\cdot a}_k$. Then my $2$-Sylow subgroup would be $Syl_2G = \{1, 6\}$ which isn't $4$ elements. I think I'm missing the point somehow.

Comment: What makes you think that is the Sylow $2$-subgroup? In this case, the Sylow $2$-subgroup does not consist of the elements of exponent $2$. The Sylow $2$-subgroup of the cyclic group of order $12$ is $\{1,3,6,9\}$, its cyclic subgroup of order $4$, consisting of all elements whose order is a power of $2$. That is true in any finite abelian group: the Sylow $p$-subgroup is the subgroup of elements of order a power of $p$.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin Oh, I think I was misinterpreting $p-$groups the whole time. So in that case I need to check that for an Element $x$ in $2-$Sylow it holds true that $x^{2^n} = 1$? But isn't $3^{2^n}$ and $9^{2^n}$ $\mod 12$ always $9$ $\forall n$?

Comment: Your notation is a mess. The integers modulo $12$ do not form a group under multiplication; the nonzero integers modulo $12$ do not form a group under multiplication. The units modulo $12$ do not form a group of order $12$. So my description (messed up by distraction) is $\{0,3,6,9\}$, using integers modulo $12$ under **addition**. If you want a multiplicative group of order $12$, cyclic, with generator $x$, then I mean $\{1, x^3, x^6, x^9\}$ (and you meant $\{1,x^6\}$, not $\{1,6\}$). If you mean the nonzero integers modulo $13$ (which is cyclic of order 12), then $6$ is not of order $2$.

Comment: Thanks. It's much clearer to me now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To summarize:

1. You are misinterpreting what you read; if $G$ is of order $12$, then it has *nontrivial* Sylow $p$-subgroups for exactly $p=2$ and $p=3$, because in general, a finite group has nontrivial Sylow $p$-subgroups for those primes $p$ that divide $|G|$.
2. It is false that a group of order $12$ must have four or more Sylow $2$-subgroups; in fact, no group of order $12$ can have four or more Sylow $2$-subgroups. By Sylow’s Theorems, the number of Sylow $2$-subgroups divides $|G|=12$ and is congruent to $1$ modulo $2$, hence is either $1$ or $3$. The number of *elements* in a Sylow $2$-subgroup of a group of order $12$ is exactly $4$, because the order of a Sylow $p$-subgroup of a finite group $G$ is the largest power of $p$ that divides $|G|$.
3. The alternating group $G=A_4$ is a nonabelian group of order $12$ that has exactly $1$ Sylow $2$-subgroup, namely $K=\{e, (12)(34), (13)(24), (14)(23)\}$. It has exactly four Sylow $3$-subgroups, generated by $(123)$, $(124)$, $(134)$, and $(234)$, respectively.